# Does not come any value to my dispatcher in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, dispatcher

This is part of my login component. when I try send email to emailChanged action, i take error on debug console
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `string`."

```
<TextInput
         placeholder="email"
         style={inputStyle}
         value={this.props.kullaniciadi}
         onChangeText={degisentext => this.props.emailChanged({ 
         kullaniciadi: degisentext })} 
         />
```

I am using redux framework, i want to send text that changing email to action"emailChanged" but this parameter does not go to the dispathcher.

My emailChanged action :

```
export const emailChanged = (kullaniciadi) => {
kullaniciadi.toString();
console.log('emailChange actionu calisti'+ kullaniciadi);
return (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
       type: KULLANICIADI_CHANGED,
       payload: kullaniciadi
   }     
   );     
 };
};
```

And my component include this connect to access reducers and actions :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged })(LoginForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an object to `emailChanged` function, so you need to access `kullaniciadi` as a property of that object like this

```
export const emailChanged = (obj) => {
    let kullaniciadi = obj.kullaniciadi;

    kullaniciadi.toString();
    console.log('emailChange actionu calisti'+ kullaniciadi);
    return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({
           type: KULLANICIADI_CHANGED,
           payload: kullaniciadi
       });     
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it but didn't work. I think my problem is my datas doesn't arrive to emailChanged action as a parameter. I logged it but always this obj is undefined. Thanks for your interesting.